# Using late binding to call a private method from a non private context

Tags: c++, inheritance, class-visibility

I was surprised by the output produced by the piece of code below (`g++ 4.4.7`).

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f() {std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl;}
};

class B : public A {
private:
    // Automatically virtual, because of base class
    void f() {std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl;}
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    A *pB = new B();
    pB->f();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
B::f()
```

I know that because of late binding the compiler cannot issue an error here, but why can we call a private method from a non-private context?

What is the rationale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

n3376 11.5.1

> The access rules (Clause 11) for a virtual function are determined by its declaration and are not affected by
> the rules for a function that later overrides it.

11.5.2

> Access is checked at the call point using the type of the expression used to denote the object for which the
> member function is called. The access of the member function in the class in
> which it was defined (D in the example above) is in general not known.

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for! Couldn't find it in the standard myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Access specifiers only exist for compilation purposes. Any memory within your program's allocation can be accessed by any part of the executable; there is no public/private concept at runtime

Late binding functions are run time so there is no public and private concept for run time

Comment: Can you please indicate the source of the quote (or remove quoting block if those are your own words :))?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have tried to execute this code with little modification to make specify base
 class virtual function in private section and I got error from compiler. because in compile
 time first control goes to base class function but it is defined in private section so
 compiler throw error . Whenever you declare a object of the derived class taking the
 reference of base class. In compile time control goes to base class first and every class 
 makes its own virtual table and then run time the pointer object invoke derived class 
 function and no matters where it is declared private or public as I said earlier.

```
   class A {
         virtual void f() {std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl;}
  };

class B : public A {
   private:
     // Automatically virtual, because of base class
      void f() {std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl;}
 };

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
 {
  A *pB = new B();
   pB->f();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: We are calling f() through the base class pointer,thats why the control goes to the base class first.